# Cartridge replacement on this faucet (or help identify the faucet)

Tags: plumbing, faucet, bathtub

I have this old faucet. Has no markings or branding on it. Probably from late 1980s. The faucet is leaking and I can't identify the brand to order replacement cartridges. Any experts out there that can help identify this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is a different faucet of same design for reference as well.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if new cartridges could be almost the same cost as a new faucet.

Comment: The faucets are on the rim of the bathtub, and it seems there is no access to the plumbing without breaking the tiles. The entire job seems much more expensive than getting the cartridges. 

Any creative ideas to access the plumbing short of destroying the tiles?

Comment: That's a different question and shouldn't be presented in a comment. Please take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

Comment: @Asim sorry, I can barely see the tiles due to the picture size...

Comment: You are  in a better position than most because you have been able to remove the cartridges.   Take them to a good, dedicated plumbing supplier.  If replacements exist, they will know. If not, they look like maybe they could be overhauled.  A flat washer, a ring washer (maybe), a  new screw or two ....

Comment: Are you able to unscrew the top flat-head screw (that holds the plastic bit)? If this is removable- the rest of the cartridge looks quite generic to me, and probably the plastic bit just needs to be moved to the new cartridge.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly Grohe. See this [related discussion](https://terrylove.com/forums/index.php?threads/help-removing-2-grohe-shower-tub-handles-with-no-screws.59023/).

Comment: Thanks! 
This seems comparable: https://www.grohe.ca/bathroom-faucet-fittings-and-spare-parts/ceramic-cartridge/grohe-chrome-45346000

Comment: Checked with Grohe and it is not their faucet.

Answer (score 0):

Could be simbolo that's all I'm guessing

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/179641)